# Is it possible to disable network only for current command session?

Tags: bash

I have a script that compiles a program, but it takes more than 2 hours to compile it. When I disable the network adapter of all the windows system, the compile time changes to 30 minutes and the compiling is still successful. This is because when compiling, the script accesses some network files, but actually those accesss are not strictly necessary to compile. So I would like to disable network access only for that CMD session so that I can continue using the network in the rest of my system. Is that possible?

Comment: If the files aren't really necessary, why not just take them out of the compilation script?

Comment: [su] would be a better place to ask about this.

Comment: You could set a proxy (to localhost for example) for terminal, but i don't know if you can do it for only the current session..

Comment: You didn't mention the OS, so I assume it's Linux. You can use http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html (see also https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/unshare.html)

Comment: Oh yes!... sorry!, it is Windows, and must be compatible with Windows 7 and later. thank you! :)